# How to 'tab' through headings in a Microsoft Word document (keyboard shortcut request)

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts

I know the keyboard shortcuts for applying headings such as `ctrl` + `alt` + `1` but am wondering if there is a way to jump down to the next heading or up to the previous one. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean a keyboard command that will skip the Paragraph content and jump from one Heading line to the next/previous?

Answer (score 3):

#### <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd>, but after some preparation.

[image: 1]

1. from **Home** ribbon tab, navigate to **Advanced Find...** (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>).
2. On **Go To** tab, select **Headings** and you can close the window if you wish (or keep it open but click the document).
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> and
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd> to navigate to previous/next heading.

In the same way you can navigate through any of listed object types.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks! Very useful for projecting a live Word display :)

Comment: @teepee - Did this work for you as well? If yes, maybe you can accept the answer.